# Can make warn me, when I use unset variables?

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to tell make to complain when I use unset variables? Something similar to `set -u` in bash?

I have just spent twenty minutes debugging my Makefile, because there was a one symbol typo in the name of the variable.

Comment: Some combination of `if` and `$(error ...)` should do it for you.

Comment: There is a related feature request: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?63737

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```
make --warn-undefined-variables
```

I've just tested it with make version **3.81**

EDIT:

You can also set it in your makefile, to protect yourself in the future from silly mistakes.
To do it just put this somewhere near the top of your makefile (this will be passed to recursive make processes too):

```
MAKEFLAGS=--warn-undefined-variables
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to trigger it in the Makefile itself, rather than using command line option?

Comment: Yes, you can put it into your makefile(s) too, please see the edit of my answer.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't you do += instead of = ? I am still confused with make's assignment operators.

Comment: Setting it in the `Makefile` does not trigger a warning for something like `$(info $(UNUSED))` though.. (GNU Make 4.2.1)

Comment: Gosh, how I wish `--error-undefined-variables` existed

Comment: @AntonDaneyko Yes, I think += probably adds the flags from the file rather than overriding the current flags, which would be better.  But I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how one can do it to make make fail immediately:

```
ifndef PSWD
$(error PSWD is undefined)
endif
```